# How to make input[type="date"] accessible via keyboard and mouse?

Tags: javascript, html, css, datepicker, accessibility

I have used a native html5 input date-picker in my code, It's working fine for me so far(i am only concerned about chrome and edge). But I am facing one issue:
I want a uniform way to access the date picker but I notice that in my date picker there is a date picker button(pseudo-element) which is not accessible via keyboard, I tried to remove the pseudo-element by making its display none but then I lose the functionality to open the pop-up calendar via mouse.

- we have to press space to open via the keyboard as the icon is not accessible via the
  keyboard.
- we have to click on the icon to open the calendar popup via mouse.

As per accessibility standards if an element is accessible via mouse it should be accessible by keyboard too. so I need a work-around that.

I am looking for one of the following solutions - (any one of them will work)

1. Making the date icon accessible by keyboard.
2. Removing the date icon and making the calendar popup via mouse click instead of clicking on the icon.

Does anyone know the solution to this issue?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DatePicker</title>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="mydate">DOB:</label>
    <input type="date" id="mydate">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tabbing to the entry and pressing space will open the date picker

Comment: Yes tabbing and pressing space will open it but as there is an icon which is an intractive element it should also be accessible via keyboard too, but it is not.

Comment: @AbhishekTomar You can use left and right arrow keys to move between day, month and year. Then up and down to pick the correct one.

Comment: yeah the problem is that there is no uniform way of opening the popup calendar, we have to click on the calendar icon or space bar, it is not compliant as per accessibility standards I wanted a uniform way for both mouse and keyboard but the icon is not accessible via keyboard.

Comment: @AbhishekTomar What is wrong with tab, space and arrow keys?

Comment: @AbhishekTomar *"there is an icon which is an interactive element it should also be accessible via keyboard too"*. Make sure you fully understand WCAG 2.1.1. That success criterion does **not** say that every element must be keyboard accessible but rather that *"all functionality"* is keyboard accessible. If the icon is used to display the calendar but is not keyboard focusable but you can also display the calendar by pressing spacebar on one of the date parts, then the *functionality* **IS** accessible.

Comment: Thanks i guess that solves my issue as I can see its accessible following this guideline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a native element, so by definition, there is no unique solution, since every browser can implement it differently.

This is both the advantage and the disadvantage of native elements.
If it's accessible, it's the best; if it isn't accessible, it's in fact not your responsibility to fix it, but rather that of browser implementers.

If you try to fix the accessibility of the component in a given environment, you have great risks to create problems on other environments where you haven't tested your fix. You normally shouldn't try to interfer with the internal working of native elements beyond what you can configure in standard.
By the way, the inaccessible button you have fund may even not be reachable in standard DOM and may thus be totally unable to do anything about it.

If you want to have full control, you will need to implement your own date picker.
Keep in mind, though, that your own solution is generally going to be less accessible than a native one.

IN general, native components are more accessible and their behavior is adapted to the running platform. Iif they currently aren't accessible, they are supposed to improve over time without the need for you to update your code.
This is why you normally should always prefer native components over any home made or library provided components.
Using native components is in principle a long term win, both for you and for users.